# Phalcon - Implement One-To-Many self-referencing relationship in model

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm, model, phalcon

How to implement this feature in the Phalcon? Doctrine has [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing). I want something similar like that. My **office** table in the database:

```
Id (PK) | ParentId | Name
```

I want a function like:

```
Office::findFirst()->children();
```

I've tried to define a Many-to-One relationship in my model but it always returns an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model:

```
namespace Models;
class ProductCategories extends BaseModel
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany('id', 'Models\ProductCategories', 'parent_id', [
            'alias' => 'children',
            'params' => [
                'order' => 'position ASC',
                'conditions' => 'active = 1', 
            ]
        ]);
    }
 }
```

*Note the full namespace.*

**Usage:**

```
$parent = \Models\ProductCategories::findFirst();
print_r($parent->children->toArray());
```

More info: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.1/db-models-relationships

Comment: could you please insert the full code of the `ProductCategories` model?

Comment: `Note the full namespace.`, try using `ProductCategories::class` instead, it's better than writing the namespace in a string. If you are going to refactor in the future, you don't need to worry about the namespace references!