# Phalcon ORM field has relation with another field in same table

Tags: php, mysql, model, phalcon, phalcon-orm

I have the following table in my mysql DB

[image: mysql]

I have a model `Shipment` and i am using Phalcon's ORM to interact with my DB. The `master_id` field in this table is actually the `id` of another raw, but in the same table, as you can see in the picture. The id=1 is the Master Shipment and id=2 and id=3 are Subshipments.

My model right now looks like this

```
class Shipment extends Model
{
    protected $id;
    protected $hawb;
    protected $master_id;

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->hasMany(
            'id',
            'Shipment',
            'master_id'
        );
    }
    //setters and getters are here
}
```

When I am using `$shipment = ShipmentModel::findFirst($id);` in my Controller, i can see the `master_id` of the `Shipment`.

What i want to have is, call another function from my `Shipment` model in order to retrieve all the `SubShipments` as a Collection of `Shipment` models, or at least an array with `Shipment` models.

Or even better, if the `ShipmentModel::findFirst($id);` could populate the `SubShipments` automatically (if there are any) would be the best!

I don't really know if the `$this->hasMany` that I have is correct over there, so if someone could show me how to proceed I would be grateful :)

Comment: There is a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534869/phalcon-implement-one-to-many-self-referencing-relationship-in-model/45535716#45535716 Please, take a look and let me know :)

Comment: `Model 'Shipment' could not be loaded
Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Manager->load('Shipment')
Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Manager->getRelationRecords(Object(Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Relation), NULL, Object(Project\API\Models\Customer\Shipment), NULL)
#2 /var/www/project/app/src/Controllers/Shipment.php(55): Phalcon\Mvc\Model->getRelated('subShipments')
#3 [internal function]: Project\API\Controllers\Shipment->getShipment('2LzXEvabvaOwWVq')
#4 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Micro\LazyLoader->__call('getShipment', Array)
#5 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Micro\LazyLoader->callMethod('getShipment', Array, NULL)`

Comment: I have a server error `Model 'Shipment' could not be loaded`. Above i pasted the exception i have in my logs. Don't know why it cannot load the model :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide full namespace, not just class name - to solve this `Model 'Shipment' could not be loaded`. Best is to add alias:

```
$this->hasMany(
    'id',
    Shipment::class,
    'master_id',
    ['alias' => 'subShipments'])
);
```

And then just use:

`Shipment::findFirst()->getSubShipments()` you can add such method if you want and do `return $this->getRelated('subShipments')`